# How does the "leftmost, longest" rule apply to subexpressions in ERE?

Tags: regex, boost-regex, posix-ere

The [POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_01_02) states that for both ERE and BRE:

> Consistent with the whole match being the longest of the leftmost matches, each subpattern, from left to right, shall match the longest possible string. For this purpose, a null string shall be considered to be longer than no match at all. For example, matching the BRE "(.*).*" against "abcdef", the subexpression "(\1)" is "abcdef", and matching the BRE "(a*)*" against "bc", the subexpression "(\1)" is the null string.

#### My question: how should `(a|ab)(c|bcd)(d*)` match against "abcd"?

My reading of the standard above is that the subexpression `(a|ab)` should match the leftmost, longest string that keeps the whole match as long as possible, so the subexpression should match "ab". However, when I used GNU regex to search for `(a|ab)(c|bcd)(d*)` in "abcd", I get the following for the first subexpression:

```
echo abcd | sed -E 's/(a|ab)(c|bcd)(d*)/\0, \1, \2, \3/'
abcd, a, bcd,
```

This example is from [this page](https://wiki.haskell.org/Regex_Posix#GNU_C_library_.28aka_GLIBC.29).

Here is a C++ code using Boost.Regex with regex::extended flag:

```cpp
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  boost::regex_constants::syntax_option_type regex_flags =
      boost::regex::extended;

  std::string text = "abcd";
  boost::regex expression("(a|ab)(c|bcd)(d*)", regex_flags);
  boost::smatch matches {};

  boost::regex_search(text, matches, expression);

  for (const auto match : matches) { std::cout << match << ", "; }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Compiling and running, produces:

```
abcd, ab, c, d,
```

Here, consistend with the standard the subexpression `(a|ab)` matches with the longest thing it can match, but in GNU regex it doesn't.

Comment: It is a regular greedy regex pattern. The first `.*` matches up to the end of string, and there is nothing left for the second `.*` to match

Comment: Subexpressions don't change how the rest of the regexp is processed. They just provide a way to group part of the regexp, either for quantification or back-referencing.

Comment: If Boost really does what you say, that sounds wrong to me.

Comment: @Barmar, in light of the updates I added, could you reopen the question? I don't believe the linked question answers the distinction between Boost.Regex and GNU regex in interpreting the ERE standard.

Comment: Alternations are implemented differently by different engines.  Some will try to find the longest match, others give precedence to the earlier alternative. https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html

Comment: @Barmar so they simply ignore the rule about leftmost, longest subexpression matches?

Comment: leftmost, longest doesn't apply to subexpressions, it applies to expressions in general.

Comment: @Barmar but the standard says "each subpattern, from left to right, shall match the longest possible string". isn't `(a|ab)` the first subpattern in the new example?

Comment: No, that's a subexpression, not a subpattern.

Comment: Unfortunately that spec is not very clear in defining its terms. In most other RE literature, what it calls a subexpression is called a capturing group.